# How to configure material components web with laravel-mix?

Tags: laravel, material-components-web

I use mdc with laravel-mix but it's not loading scss files from node modules.
I tried some other solutions about giving includepaths in mix.sass, but they are not working.

I tried code in webpack.mix.js

```
const path = require('path');
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css', {
    includePaths:  ['./node_modules']
});
```

but its still giving me same error that

> ```
>  undefined
>         ^
>        Can't find stylesheet to import. @import "@material/elevation/mixins";
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Laravel 6 I had to do it this way:

`npm install --save material-components-web`

app.scss:
`@import "material-components-web/material-components-web";`

webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css', {
    sassOptions: {
        includePaths:  ['./node_modules']
    }
});
```

Comment: That is the correct syntax for laravel-mix v5 regardless of the laravel framework version.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, answer from Edmund Sulzanok is correct, add sassOptions but for me too:

Laravel VERSION = '6.7.0';

I had to upgrade npm package.json devDependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "cross-env": "^6.0.3",
    "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
    ...,
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.1",
    "sass": "^1.25.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    ...
},
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "material-components-web": "^4.0.0",
    ...
}
```

After modify package.json run npm install

```
npm install
```

You could see Packages outdated with

```
npm outdated
```

good luck